# Least upper bound and greatest lower bound of the void set.

Tags: soft-question, lattice-orders, continuous-geometry

Let $(L,\ge)$ a partially ordered set. Suppose that for avery $S \subset L$, there exists an element $LUB(S)= a$ such that $x \ge a \iff x \ge u \quad \forall u \in S$ and, with the obvious meaning of $\le$, there exists an element $GLB(S)= b$ such that $x \le b \iff x \le u \quad \forall u \in S$.

Now: if $S=\emptyset$ is the emptyset, what are $LUB(\emptyset)$ and $GLB(\emptyset)$? Im not able to figure if this elements are defined and what they are. Someone can help  my poor intuition?

Added after the comment:

This question comes from the definition of continuous geometry of von Neumann (see [here](http://www.pnas.org/content/22/2/92) ).

He define : $LUB(\emptyset)=\mathbf 0$ and $GLB(\emptyset)=\mathbf 1$ then says that we can verify ''immediately'' that:

$
\forall a \in L \; : \; \mathbf 0 \le a \le \mathbf 1
$

and:
$
a \lor \mathbf 0 =a\;,\;a\land \mathbf 0=\mathbf 0\;,\;a\lor \mathbf 1=\mathbf 1 \;,\; a\land \mathbf 1=a
$
where the symbols $\lor$ and $\land$ have the usual meaning for a lattice.

For me this result is not at all immediate, I suppose because I've not a good intuition of what are the elements $\mathbf 0$ and $\mathbf 1$.

Comment: Probably $D$ is $S$ and $x$ is universally quantified. However, unless you require that the $LUB(S)$ is only one element (specified somehow), then $LUB(\emptyset)$ is not uniquely determined by your formula. (Of course, independent of your definition, it is reasonable to define $LUB(\emptyset)$ as the minimum of $L$ but this is not what you ask for)

Comment: @Peter. Thanks for the comment. I've added some contest to my question.

Comment: $0$ and $1$ are *defined* to be LUB resp. GLB, so then $x\geq 0$ is equivaent to "$x\geq u$ for all $u\in\emptyset$" which is true. So, $x\geq 0$ for all $x\in L$ and similarly, $x\leq 1$. By Remark 3, p. 94. these elements (defined in $II$) are unique. The intuition is simple: any element of $L$ is an upper bound of the emptyset and the *least* upper is then the minimum of all $L$.

Comment: So, if I well understand,the intuition is that $0$ is the element that is $\ge$ than nothing and $1$ is the element that is $\le$ than nothing and this means that $0\le a$ and $1 \ge a$ $\forall a \in L$. But we are sure that such elements exist in any poset ( by Axiom of Choice ?) or we have to postulate their existence?

Comment: An element that is "$\geq $ than nothing" is called a "minimal element". It is *not* the same as "smallest element". Here $0$ is rather "smallest element" (="minimum"), not only "minimal element". It doesn't exist in any posset but it follows from condition $II$ in the text you refer to. The simplest counter-example is the poset that consists of two incomparable elements, then there are no LUB's of subsets (and there is no smallest nor largest elements, although both elements are both minimal and maximal).

Comment: Thank you @Peter! Now I understand better. if You post an answer I can accept.